# Preparing Hypochlorous acid from salt water

Tags: redox, home-experiment, halides, electrolysis

I am a school student and I want help with a project

***My aim***:

Preparing Hypochlorous Acid (Suitable for sanitation).

I searched across the internet and found an article at https://www.hypochlorousacid.com/hocl-chemistry  in which Salt Water electrolysis was used to make HClO.

But I have two problems here:

1. This process entirely relies on the ion-exchange membrane.
2. Titanium anode and nickel cathode are used in this process.

These make the process a very costly affair.

***My question*** :

Is there any alternative way in which I can prepare HClO? (Probably at home).

*I could not find the suitable tags for this question. So if you can add suitable tags, please edit this question*

Comment: Given the risks involved, you should not do this type of experiment at home without teacher's supervision. Gone are the days when teenagers owned a home lab and eventually won Nobel Prizes. If it is a home project, I can give you other interesting project ideas related to spectroscopy.

Comment: I didn't mean that. I mean that I want to do this with commonly available and low-cost items (like salt and water as described in the question). And for the electrolysis part, I can do that in adult supervision. It's nice to see that you can also give me new ideas, but I would like to continue with the present project. You can definitely give some solution to the problem given in the question.

Comment: Have you seen UNESCO book of 700 Science Experiments for Everyone. This was my favorite book. Go to the electrochemistry section to see the set-up suitable for school experiments. It is available here (register to borrow the book) https://archive.org/details/700scienceexperi0000unes/page/n7/mode/2up